# Adding an external font to WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want my WP7 app controls and to have a certain font which is not in Visual studio font selection, how can I add the font to the font list of Visual studio or directly into my controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a post showing how to embed fonts in a silverlight project (see the section 'Custom Fonts'):
http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/09/09/97060.aspx

I haven't tested this in a windows phone project but it should work.

Comment: Not sure, but this link should have the necessary info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592928.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done using Expression Blend.

In your project, select a `TextBlock` and go to the Properties panel, under Text section, there is a Font Manager button (see below), click it and then you can select the font you want in a popup window.

Expression Blend will automatically create a Fonts folder and put all the embedded fonts in there, really easy to use. :)

[image]

Comment: Blend font embedding is the way to go.  You can create glyph subsets, etc. and then compress everything into a single zip file for you.  VS won't do any of that.