# How to add monospaced text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock, monospace

I need a monospace font in the TextBlock for a Windows Phone 7 app that I am working on. I tried the ones available and none of them seem to be monospace.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized that Courier New is monospaced too and it seems to work pretty fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could download a monospace font from somewhere and use it as discussed here.
[Adding an external font to WP7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079009/adding-an-external-font-to-wp7-app)

Comment: +1 - Just remember to check license details for any fonts you download and use.

Answer (score 2):

Another font that's included with Windows Phone is Segoe UI Mono. It might look better since it is part of the default "Metro" (or *Modern*) UI type family. Use it as in:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI Mono"/>
```